How do I monitor my hugo site deployed using github pages using custom domain using zabbix/promethus/grafana/monit?
Is it possible to do? I’d love to learn monitoring systems. I know that you need access to the linux server in order to  do it. But I'd love to know if it's possible or not?
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103618/analytics-on-github-pages
I am not talking about analytics. I am talking about server's resources, performance resources etc.
